# datavalue field problem in asp.net dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

Hi I've a dropdown list with datasource like

```
empname     dept
-----------------
jax         02
martin      01
sachin      02
```

i've binded this table to my dropdown list
and when i try to access dept in dropdown selected event change everytime I'm gettin jax only. even i selected sachin.

Whats the problem? What I assume is I've two common values in my datavalue field (02 and 02) is this a problem?

Thank you

Comment: Can you try with SelectedItem.Text?

Comment: It seems that problem with duplicate values in column dept. Change sachin to 03 and test again.

Comment: I fixed by adding unique id to value field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be ensure that the data-binding code is executed once.

```
if(!IsPostBack)
 {
   //put data-binding code here
 }
```

Comment: yes i did like that only. But i've two common values in datavalue field. I thought that might be a problem. When I change dept values to unique values it is working fine for me